# Information for connecting SIP user Agent with SIP server(Opensip)

Tags: c, linux, sip, opensips

I am a newbie to sip server and  i am experimenting with it using c programming.
I have installed open sip server on my ubuntu 13.04.
and i am trying to configure it.
can somebody provide me a basic example showing how a user agent registers to sip server.
Do i have to download some specific sip user agent.
if yes,can you suggest me some names
so that i can start programming in right direction.

Comment: How to deploy SIP user agent

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use XLite of course. That's free and simple enough.
http://www.counterpath.com/x-lite-download.html

For SIP and OpenSIPs you should refer to the official documentation which also have a number of nice webinars.
http://www.opensips.org/Documentation/Webinars

I advise you to start with *SIP introduction* and *Introduction to OpenSIPS*

Comment: there is no webinar showing registration of user agent with opensip server?

Comment: This one here opensips.org/Documentation/Tutorials-GettingStarted covers installation of OpenSIPS and control panel, and registering users. And, by-the-way, if you just started on VoIP you probably should check out Asterisk since it has much more examples (webinars or whatever) on the web and it much easier to set up then OpenSIPS.